# Filtering permutations of strings

Tags: python

What I'm trying to do is create a set of permutations of a string which contains a `'['` and `']'` in the string. Then, add only the strings that were created by the create_perm which contains an `'['` as the first and `']'` as the last to a new set and return that set.

**What I've done:**

```
def create_perm(lst_str):
    if len(lst_str) <= 1:
        return {lst_str}
    old_set = set()
    for idx, c in enumerate(lst_str):
        for perm in create_perm(lst_str[:idx] + lst_str[idx+1:]):
            old_set.add(c + perm)
    return old_set


def perm(lst_str):
    new_set = set()
    for idx in create_perm(lst_str):
        if idx.startswith('[') and idx.endswith(']'):
                new_set.add(idx)
    return new_set
```

**Examples:**

```
perm('[1]2')
{'[12]', '[21]'}
perm('[1]23')
{'[123]', '[213]', '[321]', '[312]', '[231]', '[132]'}
perm('[1]2,3')
{'[2,13]', '[3,21]', '[12,3]', '[,213]', '[2,31]', '[,312]', '[1,23]', '[13,2]', '[321,]', '[312,]', '[,132]', '[23,1]', '[123,]', '[,321]', '[1,32]', '[132,]', '[,231]', '[3,12]', '[32,1]', '[21,3]', '[213,]', '[,123]', '[31,2]', '[231,]'}
```

so,

first I create the permutations of a string which contain a '[' and ']' within:

```
>>> create_perm('[2,],1')
{',]2,[1', '2,1,][', '2][1,,', ',][2,1', ']2,1,[', ',[,]12', '1,],[2', ',[2,1]', ',[12],', '2[,]1,', '1][,,2', ',,]2[1', '1[2,],', ...}
```

then return a new set with only the strings that begin with '[' and ends with ']

```
>>> perm('[2,],1')
{'[,2,1]', '[2,,1]', '[12,,]', '[1,,2]', '[,12,]', '[,21,]', '[21,,]', '[2,1,]', '[,,21]', '[,1,2]', '[,,12]', '[1,2,]'}
```

I can just call perm and that will call create_perm within.

The problem with this is that it can take quite a while when more characters are added to the string. But I think I know what to do to increase the speed a bit, and here's my idea:

**Idea:**

When creating the permutations of the string, don't bother adding/creating strings that don't start with `'['` and end with `']'` into the set, then we can simply remove the perm function which loops through each item and checks if the string starts with a `'['` and ends with a `']'`. In the end, there will be less amount of items to check therefore increasing the speed.

But how would of I go upon changing the create_perm function to not create strings that don't start with '[' and end with ']'?

Any help would be appreciated. If there is an even more better approach than my idea please let me know

Comment: There's probably an easier way to do this by leveraging something like [itertools.permutations](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just strip them out, you don't need them to generate the perms.

```
def create_perm(lst_str):
    li = list(lst_str.replace('[','').replace(']',''))
    for perm in itertools.permutations(li):
        yield '[{}]'.format(''.join(perm))
```

demo:

```
list(create_perm('[1]2,'))
Out[102]: ['[12,]', '[1,2]', '[21,]', '[2,1]', '[,12]', '[,21]']
```

This uses [`itertools.permutations`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) instead of recursively generating the perms.

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you strip out the brackets, generate all permutations of the resulting string, then put the brackets around each result?